# Array and reference

Tags: php-5.3

```
<?php 
  /* Assignment of array variables */
  $arr = array(1);
  $a =& $arr[0]; //$a and $arr[0] are in the same reference set
  $arr2 = $arr; //not an assignment-by-reference!
  $arr2[0]++;
?>
```

The output is `$a == 2`, `$arr == array(2)`.
The contents of `$arr` are changed even though it's not a reference!

Can anyone tell how is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP all array copying is by reference. You need to explicitly copy something if you want a shallow copy.

So even though you don't assign to `$arr2` by reference, since `$arr` is an array they both end up referring to the same array object.